# How do I create a unique index within a Rails create table migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, rake, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 and PostgreSQL 9.5.  How do I create a unique index within my table?  I want to create the unique index out of two columns, which are themselves references to other tables.  So I tried

```
class CreateUserNotificationsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_notifications do |t|
      t.references :users, index: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.references :crypto_currencies, index: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.integer  "price",      null: false
      t.boolean "buy",      null: false
      t.index [:user_id, :crypto_currency_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

but I'm getting the error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" does not exist
: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "index_user_notifications_on_user_id_and_crypto_currency_id" ON "user_notifications"  ("user_id", "crypto_currency_id")
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `block in execute'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:590:in `block in log'
```

What's the right way to create the unique index within the create table statement?

Comment: Do you have `user_id` column persisted in `user_notifications` table? Check with `UserNotification.column_names`

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I have this "t.references :users, index: true, on_delete: :cascade" just below "create table" so shouldn't that create a "user_id" column?

Comment: When I run the above migration, it fails and no user_notifications table is created.  I see the statements, "create_table(:user_notifications)" followed by "rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:" followed by the error I posted above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" does not exist

The problem is `t.references :users` creates a column called `users_id` not `user_id`, so it unable to create an index with `t.index [:user_id, :crypto_currency_id], unique: true` as the column `user_id` is not created which resulted in that error.

**Solution:**

Just change it to `t.references :user`. Same goes for `t.references :crypto_currencies` too.

```
class CreateUserNotificationsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_notifications do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.references :crypto_currency, index: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.integer  "price",      null: false
      t.boolean "buy",      null: false
      t.index [:user_id, :crypto_currency_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract index of `create_table` method, like:

```
class CreateUserNotificationsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_notifications do |t|
      t.references :users, index: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.references :crypto_currencies, index: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.integer  "price",      null: false
      t.boolean "buy",      null: false
    end

    add_index :user_notifications, [:user_id, :crypto_currencies_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you saying its impossible to create a table and include a unique index definition within the table creation block?